# p:dataTable sorting and filtering error

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

I've made globalFilter in the header of dataTable and then added sorting to columns. But there is a problem: the columns becoming sortable after the first time I use the filter.

So when the program starts user need to clear already empty filter control and after that can sort data in the table.

Please,could someone recommend me how to solve the problem?
I've made filter like in example on [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).

```
<p:dataTable id="dtParkType"
             widgetVar="w_dtParkType"
             var="parkTypeWeb"
             value="#{parkTypeHolder.data}"
             selectionMode= "single"
             selection="#{parkTypeController.selectedItem}"
             rowKey="#{parkTypeWeb.id}"
             emptyMessage="#{msg['common.NoValue']}"
             rowStyleClass="#{parkTypeWeb.isDeleted? 'colored' : null}"
             filteredValue="#{parkTypeController.filteredData}"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollRows="27"
             paginator="true"
             rows="27"
             resizableColumns="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <div align="right">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['edit.Search']}"/>
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                             onkeyup="PF('w_dtParkType').filter()"
                             style="width:150px;margin-left:5px;"
                             placeholder="#{msg['common.PlaceHolder.KeyWord']}"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{parkTypeController.onRowSelect}"
            update=":rightForm:panelbtnParkType"/>

    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
            listener="#{parkTypeController.callEditForm}"
            update=":formEditParkType:pnlEditParkType"/>

    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":rightForm:panelbtnParkType"/>

    <p:column filterBy="#{parkTypeWeb.longName}"
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              filterStyle="display:none"
              sortBy="#{parkTypeWeb.longName}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['column.Title.Full']}"/>
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{parkTypeWeb.longName}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{parkTypeWeb.shortName}"
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              filterStyle="display:none"
              sortBy="#{parkTypeWeb.shortName}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['column.Title.Short']}"/>
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{parkTypeWeb.shortName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: PF version? Since there have been known issues in this regard (check the PF issuelist)

Comment: PF version is 5.1,the latest of free